# How to trigger click event for p:selectOneButton in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PF 5.3, with JSF 2.2 and jQuery of PrimeFaces 5.3 (v1.11.3)

In client side script, I want to trigger click event of `p:selectOneButton`, so it is same if a human select a choice in the browser.

xhtml:

```
<h:form id="register_new_student" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <p:selectOneButton id="newStudentGender" value="#{newStudentPresentation.newPerson.gender}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="Male" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="Female" />
  </p:selectOneButton>
</h:form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('register_new_student:newStudentGender:0')).trigger('click.selectOneButton');
```

But this jQuery code didn't work, any help?

Comment: Your xhtml doesn't match jQuery. In xhtml you got `id="register_new_student"` and in jQuery `register_edit_student`. On the side adding `javascript` and `jquery` tags you will get answers from people knowing nothing in JSF. If you want help from pure javascript/jQuery side don't post JSF xhtml but generated HTML.

Comment: @John: learn some basic debugging skills. Step1 is seeing if you can actually find the **right** html element. Next is to see if you can click it. Now your problem could be either. And _"… did not work"_ is not smart

Comment: That was in the comments, as I was writing the code here manually. But in the original project file, I have it correct.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks, the problem was not the element selector as you can see in the answered question. I just have to remove ".selectOneButton" from "click.selectOneButton". Can you please check the sample project in other question in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570383/pcommandbutton-unable-to-update-pinputtext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#register_new_student\\:newStudentGender\\:0').click();
```

With `PrimeFaces` escaping function would be like this:

```
$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('register_new_student:newStudentGender:0')).click();
```

// the (`\\:)` on the selector id is to escape the special character `:` 
as `jQuery` states see http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I guess escaping is done by `escapeClientId` in posted code.

Comment: $('#register_new_student\\:newStudentGender div.ui-button:eq(0) input').click(); didn't work actually

Comment: I tried also $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('register_new_student:newStudentGender div.ui-button:eq(0) input')).click(); but didn't work

Comment: @John From the question is there is ``register_edit_student:editStudentGender`` and ``register_new_student:newStudentGender`` which is the right selector

Comment: @John try run ``$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('register_new_student:newStudentGender'))`` to make sure it exists.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it is register_new_student in the code, but because I wrote it here without copy paste. Thanks, works like a charm

Comment: @john: never ever manually write code here again, **always** copy-paste. Saves the ones trying to help a lot of time and possible frustration

Comment: @John I also found out that your orginal answers works prefectly but with simple ``.click()``  or ``.trigger('click')`` not ``.trigger('click.selectOneButton')``

``click.selectOneButton`` event will only do a logical not an UI click as well.

Comment: @Kukeltje I know the basics of debugging skills. Thanks for your basic advice but that I know. Better to get a solution on matter.

Comment: @YouYou Thanks for your solutions, things are working. I am surprised when it didn't work because I make sure the id was correct as I checked rendered id in FireBug in FireFox. However, I thought there is special type of event for PrimeFaces. Thanks. That helped alot. Thumbs up

Comment: Then why don't you apply those skills? Not only in this question, but also tblhe others…

Answer (score -2):

go for the ID

```js
function Logme(){
  
  $("#logSpan").html('clicked');
  
  
  }

$("#newStudentGender").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="Logme()" id="newStudentGender">Click</button>
<span id="logSpan">Not clicked</span>
```

Comment: Bad answer. Manually including a way newer jquery version is bad practice in PrimeFaces and the answer is for the rest totally not PrimeFaces related